# Hermes is not enabled

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-hermes

I want to use hermes on react native.

`android/app/build.gradle`

```
  project.ext.react = [
      entryFile: "index.js",
-     enableHermes: false  // clean and rebuild if changing
+     enableHermes: true  // clean and rebuild if changing
  ]
```

Added in `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.jni.** { *; }
```

`$ cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Done above things still when I log it, it shows `false`.

```
console.log("isHermes", !!global.HermesInternal)
```

What should I do in this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the contents of `android/app/build.gradle` actually have:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false  // clean and rebuild if changing
    enableHermes: true  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

Because if you have `enableHermes` two times with `false` and `true`, it will not work properly, make sure it is:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true
]
```

Then you need to `clean` and `rebuild` the app

```bash
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew clean
$ cd ..
$ npm run android
```